# Can an iif statement produce the value of another field?

Tags: ms-access, iif

I have an Iif statement in my ms access query that is not producing an outcome.  I require it to look at the value of a field, and if it's blank show the value of another field, if not blank, show its value

Purchase: IIf([NewPurchasePrice]="",[PurchasePrice],[NewPurchasePrice])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `NewPurchasePrice` is not an empty string but `Null`. You can test for it with `IsNull(NewPurchasePrice)`. If you want to be sure to test for both `Null` and empty string, you can write `Nz(NewPurchasePrice)=""`. `Nz()` converts `Null` to the special value `Empty` which is compatible with the default value of a type. For an `Integer`, for instance, `Nz(Null) = 0`, for strings `Nz(Null) = ""`, etc.

For a price whose type is probably `Decimal` or `Double`, just write

```
 Purchase: IIf(IsNull([NewPurchasePrice]),[PurchasePrice],[NewPurchasePrice])
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Worked like a charm.  Thank you!